# Open cross origin domain and input form values

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm trying to develop a simple website that opens another website and prefills a form in the opened window.

My requirements are:

- Even though both websites belong to me they are on a different domain
- I am not able to change the opened website

What i tried so far:

- using window.open to open a new browser window => i'd have to wait for the document to ready until i can detect my input fields but i'm not allowed to do so since its cross domain
- using an iframe => i am not allowed to open the other website inside an iframe since it has X-Frame-Options set to 'sameorigin'

Are there any other possibilities to achieve this **without changing the opened website**?
If it's not possible without changing the opened website would it be enought to allow it being using inside an iframe?

Comment: no, you can't, due to *security* issues if you could

Comment: If it's possible without changing the opened website (regardless that they're both your website), won't that become a huge liability if a random site can open, say, my Google Drive page and wreaking havoc there?

Comment: TBH i also hope there is no way to do that because it would be a security issue but nevertheless i wanted to be 100% sure about it not being possible. That's why i asked.